# Finding the order of a coset of a quotient group.

Tags: group-theory, free-abelian-group

I'm dealing with free abelian groups and I encountered the following question:

Let $A$ be an abelian free group with a basis $\{x_1, x_2, x_3\}.$
Let $B$ be subgroup of A generated by $x_1+x_2+4x_3$, $2x_1-x_2+2x_3$.
Find the order of the coset $(x_1+2x_3)+B$.

**Approach:**
By definition the order of the coset is the minimal k$\in$$N$ such that $k(x_1+2x_3)+B=B$ **iff** $k(x_1+2x_3)\in B$ **iff** there exist $m_1, m_2\in N$ such that $kx_1+2kx_3=m_1(x_1+x_2+4x_3)+m_2(2x_1-x_2+2x_3)$. Adding things together I get that $m_1=m_2$ and $(k-3m_1)x_1+(2k-6m_1)x_3=0$. Therefore choosing $m_1=1, k=3$ the equation holds and the order is 3.

Is that correct?

Comment: For this particular problem, it is probably more straight forward to just see what the elements with no $x_2$-term in $B$ look like.

Comment: You wrote $2x_1-x_2+\color{red}2x_3$ instead of $2x_1-x_2+x_3$ in your calculation.

Comment: I had a typo in the description, fixed now. Sorry about that!

Comment: Okay @Tamir.  So the order should be $3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$3x_1+6x_3=(x_1+x_2+4x_3)+(2x_1-x_2+2x_3)\in B$ and  $3(x_1+2x_3)=3x_1+6x_3$.  From there it follows that  it has order $3$.  (Use that it's a torsion element in $\Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z_3$).

Comment: I don't understand what you wrote, could you elaborate please?

Comment: I'm thinking we need a multiple of $x_1+2x_3$ to be a multiple of $3x_1+5x_3$, the latter of which is in $B$.  But no multiple works.

Comment: I edited the question because of a typo in the description.